# ObjectMapper and arrays with unique keys

Tags: swift, objectmapper

Im running into an issue with ObjectMapper and the way a json response is coming back from a server.
Is there a way to have ObjectMapper parse this response and create an array of rooms?

Currently I cannot straight map the json as the keys are unique, and will change every request, as well I cannot use the ObjectMapper way of accessing nested objects with dot notation, `rooms.0.key` as I am unsure how many objects there are, as well as the key that will show up.

Is there a simple way of parsing this reponse.

[image]

```
"rooms": {
        "165476": {
            "id": "165476",
            "area": {
                "square_feet": 334,
                "square_meters": 31
            },
        "165477": {
            "id": "165477",
            "area": {
                "square_feet": 334,
                "square_meters": 31
            },
```

Comment: Add the Json here in text format.

Comment: @PGDev added to the question.

Comment: Drop `ObjectMapper` in favor of `Codable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`Codable`** to parse the above *JSON* response.

**Models:**

```
struct Rooms: Codable {
    let rooms: [String:Room]
}
 
struct Room: Codable {
    let id: String
    let area: Area
}

struct Area: Codable {
    let squareFeet: Int
    let squareMeters: Int
}
```

**Parse** the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let response = try decoder.decode(Rooms.self, from: data)
    print(response.rooms.first?.key) //for the above json it will print "165476"
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```